# SharedMappings in Module Federation Plugin not found

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to share my shared auth library in my microfrontends in the SharedMappings in the webpackconfig but whenever I serve the app I get the following error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\stefa\Local_Storage\advanced-nx-workspace\node_modules@flight-workspace\shared\util-auth'

So it seems like it is searching in the node_modules instead of using the typescript path mapping from the tsconfig.

webpackconfig:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const mf = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');
const path = require('path');
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.base.json'), [
  '@flight-workspace/shared/util-auth',
]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: 'passenger',
    publicPath: 'auto',
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    },
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: 'module' },

      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: 'passenger',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js', // <-- Metadata generated by webpack
      exposes: {
        './Module': './apps/passenger/src/app/passenger/passenger.module.ts',
      },

      shared: share({
        '@angular/core': {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
        },
        '@angular/common': {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
        },
        '@angular/common/http': {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
        },
        '@angular/router': {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
        },

        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors(),
      }),
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Please update npm than check `npm update`